# How can I make my links enabled and disabled with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
 <button id="refreshLink" class="blue" type="button" title="Refresh Grid"
                data-entity="Topic"
                data-href="/Admin/Contents/Reference">
                <span class="center-icon sprite-arrow-circle"></span></button>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
$('#refreshLink')
.click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("blue")) {
        $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('grey');
        refreshGrid($(this).attr('data-entity')); ;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I thought that this would stop multiple clicks but it still seems to let the user click more than once and get multiple refreshes.

Is there a way I can disable and enable the links using jQuery? Also is there some queue that clicks go into if a user clicks multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select the element by it's class:

```
$('button.blue').click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('grey');
    refreshGrid($(this).attr('data-entity')); ;
    return false;
});
```

or use jQuery `one()` method:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
$('#refreshLink').one('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('grey');
    refreshGrid($(this).attr('data-entity')); ;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion for me. Do you think there's any difference between me having this in place and disabling the button. I thought I noticed multiple clicks giving more than one refresh.

Comment: One more question. How can I adapt what you wrote to check when the id is "refreshLink" and it's button.blue?

Comment: @Anne you can use jQuery `one()` method and the handler is executed once per element.

Comment: I just had a quick look about .one on the jQuery web site. What does it mean "once per element". If it is once then how can I execute it again if I want another referesh a few minutes later? Out of the two methods you suggested, which would you use?

Comment: @Anne it means that the handler is executed only once, for example if you have 10 elements that have the same classes, the handler is executed once for each of them. It depends on what the logic is. when do you want to click again on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the refresh for only those buttons that have the class of blue. Also you may want to use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to switch between the classes.

```
$('#refreshLink.blue').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('blue grey');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    refreshGrid($(this).attr('data-entity')); ;
    return false;
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dxwQH/)

Comment: How can I make the selector just work for #refreshLink ? Also do you think I need to set it disabled if I use this checking of class as a means to decide if the button does anything or not?

Comment: I guess you dont really need to do the disabling as well if you are performing this check. If you decide not to though, ensure that your class makes the button look disabled.